# Infopath: combobox and dropdown disabled when used in SharePoint 2010 Custom Task From for VS Workflow

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, workflow, infopath

I'm trying to add combobox filled form secondary data connection (SOAP service) to Custom Infopath Task Form. Everything works ok in Preview but when I deploy Workflow on SP my combobox is disabled?

Data connections files are centrally managed on SP.

I've even tried to enter choices manually in combobox properties but still when I publish form this combo (or dropdown) is disabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue by applaying steps from [here](http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/t/7384.aspx?PageIndex=1) and setting new fields to default values in Workflow code (Wf serializes form data).